# Minimal polynomial of matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation, minimal-polynomials

In field theory,I studied minimal polynomial of an algebraic element.In linear algebra,there is a similar thing known as minimal polynomial associated with a matrix.I am not very comfortable with the notion of minimal polynomial of matrices.Can someone suggest a book or note to study minimal polynomial of matrices?

Comment: To get a quick overview https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)

Comment: If you're more comfortable with the field theory approach, then I suspect that "Abstract Algebra" by Dummit and Foote is a good textbook to consult for this.

Comment: If you are familiar with the operation of substituting an $F$-linear operator or a square matrix (over a field $F$) into a polynomial (also over $F$), as happens for instance in the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, then the minimal polynomial of a square matrix $A$ is the minimal degree monic polynomial for which "$A$ is a root", in the sense that the substitution gives the zero matrix (similarly for an operator). The minimal polynomial of an algebraic element over $F$ is just the minimal polynomial of (the $F$-linear operator of) multiplication by that element.